# не подключается дополнение гостевой ОС windows 10 > xubuntu 18.4 ошибка E_fail (0x80004005)

Tags: linux, windows, virtualbox

[image]

Здравствуйте! Обновлял виртуалбокс, пробовал менять названия в папках виртуальной машины, пробовал через терминал устанавливать вручную, осталось только для меня переустанавливать виртуалку, можете подсказать решение проще? Или хотя бы направление его нахождения, заранее спасибо

Comment: В настройках виртуальной машины у вас видимо в cd-привод примонтирован образ. Отмонтируйте его. (Оставьте пустым). Или создайте ещё один контроллер.

Comment: помогло, спасибо! Вопрос можно закрывать